# Hibernate - using @JoinColumn without declaring a relationship

Tags: hibernate, joincolumn

Is it possible to use @JoinColumn in hibernate without declaring a relationship? I need to know if I can map an Object without declaring a relationship. (I know it defeats the purpose of having an ORM but I'm curious if it's possible) Example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
public Class Person {

   @Id
   private int id;

   @JoinColumn(name="ADDRESS_ID")
   private Address address  //address is also an entity
}
```

Comment: You mean a relationship as in a foreign key constraint?

Comment: Yes. I want to know if it's possible to map an Object property without a foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@JoinColumn` annotation specifies a column for joining an entity association or element collection, it doesn't specify association type. Therefore, you should use it together with `@ManyToOne` and other related annotations.

Comment: I see. If I removed the annotations (both JoinColumn and ManyToOne or other related annotations), will hibernate still consider the mapping of the Object?

Comment: @user3326840 You should get an exception if you try to compile it.